# What are the parameters and configuration required to connect HA 1.2 Zigbee

Tags: zigbee

I have a Zigbee Network from a company with Zigbee gateway that acts as a coordinator and connects Lights, dimmers, curtain controller etc.  I need to add more features to the gateway to improve it. I have asked the support and they are ready to provide me any required information that can help me to use another device in place of their gateway.

Hence I can utilize the TI zigbee development kit's coordinator. Now I am still fairly novice in zigbee and am trying to read and learn. I would like to know what all specific data (profiles ,configs , etc) from this supplier I would require to achieve this.

Here is what is known so far:

- It is based on Zigbee Pro 2007
- It uses HA 1.2 public profile

Comment: Welcome to the site, can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Your title asks for parameters and configurations, is that your question?

Comment: @Helmar yes ! I need to use a standard HA 1.2 coordinator- gateway and use it in place of another gateway which is coordinator for a HA 1.2 network